# I want to know about mongodb

Tags: java, node.js, mongodb, api

I'm currently creating an API server that reads and writes. Using MongoDB

The library uses Mongoose.

I wonder if `db.close()` must be used when reading and writing.

datamodel.js:

```
var db = mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost/testdb', {useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology:true});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

.....
Boards = mongoose.model("boards", BoardSchema);
exports.Boards = Boards;
```

routes/getList.js:

```
let result = await Boards.find().sort({"date": -1});
```

Should I close the DB declared above with `db.close()` when reading or writing?

Comment: I dont see any java code here.You should use `mongoose.connection.close()`

Comment: Is it necessary to close it?

Comment: Probably not strictly _necessary_ (consult your Mongoose documentation to know for sure),, but never wrong and always a good idea (when done correctly).

Answer (score 1):

(Very generic answer, but should help you get started with what to research)

Closing MongoDB connection depends on how is the connection established in the first place.

1. Are you initialising the connection on server startup: If yes, you should not close the connection. (*But initialising the connection on server startup is bad idea because, if connection is lost to server (like database server restart), then you would also have to restart the application or set [`reconnectTries`](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/connections.html#options)*)
2. Are you using `connection pool`: If you are using connection pool, then closing and opening of connections is taken care by Mongoose itself. All you have to do is, `release` the connection after use, so that, it's available for other requests.
3. Are you creating connection per request: If yes, then you should close the connection before returning the response or you would quickly run out of available connections at database server.

Comment: I did not use pool. ** var db = mongoose.connect ('mongodb: // localhost / testdb', {useNewUrlParser: true, useUnifiedTopology: true});
mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;

Comment: The library uses Mongoose....I've heard that Mongoose does DB.close () automatically. is not it?

Answer (score 0):

you can call [mongoose.disconnect()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#mongoose_Mongoose-disconnect) to close the connection